# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los elementos de un objeto JSON con AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json, api

Tengo el siguiente objeto JSON con el cual quiero obtener 2 cosas, el tipo 1 dentro de types y northeast que está dentro de bounds:

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "address_components" : [
        {
          "long_name" : "Nombre 1",
          "types" : [ "tipo 1", "tipo 2" ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address" : "Ejemplo 1",
      "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
          "northeast" : {
            "lat" : 25.631267,
            "lng" : -103.3094176
          }
        },
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 25.5428443,
          "lng" : -103.4067861
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Quiero hacerlo usando AngularJS con el servicio y controlador que he creado, si no se que me falta para lograrlo, necesito ayuda.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

//Servicio para obtener un objeto de una API
.service("srv", function($http){
  this.getObject = function(nombre, callback) {
    $http.get("https://ejemplo.com/api/"+nombre).then(callback);
  }
})

//Controlador para obtener el objeto JSON del servicio
.controller("ctrl", function($scope, srv){

  //Esta es una función que obtiene un nombre desde un input de HTML
  $scope.getNombre = function(nombre) {
    srv.getObject(nombre, (response)=>{
      $scope.objectResponse = response.data; //Aquí obtengo el objeto
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta te podría ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931623/7544650

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo usando los datos que pides atraves del `JSON` que presentas, quizás te puede ayudar a consumir los datos que necesitas que en este caso son, `el tipo 1` dentro de types y `northeast` que está dentro de bounds.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])



//Controlador para obtener el objeto JSON del servicio
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $http){

  //Esta es una función que obtiene un nombre desde un input de HTML
  $http.get('data.json').then(function(data){
    $scope.datos = data.data;
  });
});
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html ng-app="myApp"> 
 <head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>   
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="algo in datos">
        <div ng-repeat="fax in algo[0]">
            <div ng-repeat="exam in fax">
                <span>{{ exam.types[0] }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="ff in datos">
            <div ng-repeat="ll in ff[0]">
                <span>{{ ll.bounds.northeast }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el `json` que tienes.

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "address_components" : [
        {
          "long_name" : "Nombre 1",
          "types" : [ "tipo 1", "tipo 2" ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address" : "Ejemplo 1",
      "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
          "northeast" : {
            "lat" : 25.631267,
            "lng" : -103.3094176
          }
        },
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 25.5428443,
          "lng" : -103.4067861
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Si deseas mostrar entonces la `lat` o `lng` solo tienes que agregar en el `ng-repeat` de `<span>{{ ll.bounds.northeast }}</span>` lo siguiente:

`<span>{{ ll.bounds.northeast.lat }}</span>` y para la `lng` `<span>{{ ll.bounds.northeast.lng }}</span>` espero que te sirva de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @DanielleLewis si crees que esta respuesta fue suficiente para dar solución a tu pregunta, marca como correcta.